# Relation, union, intersection

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $X$. Then prove that $R\cup R^{-1}$ is the smallest symmetric relation containing $R$ and $R\cap R^{-1}$ is the largest symmetric relation contained in $R$.

Comment: Do you define $R^{-1}$ to be $R^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in X\times X:(y,x)\in R\}$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: This is *fairly* straightforward verification of the definitions of "symmetric relation" and "contained/containing". It would be helpful for us to help you if you can at least point out the problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

The largest symmetric relation containing R is X×X.
If R = {(0,1)}:  R$^{-1}$ = {(1,0)}; R $\cap$ R$^{-1}$ is empty;  does not contain R.

On the other hand if R is a relation, then  Rs = R $\cup$ R$^{-1}$ is symmetric and contains R.
There are two cases to prove Rs is symmetric.  What are they?
To prove Rs is the smallest symmetric relation containing R,
assume Q is a symmetric relation containg R.
Prove Rs is a subset of Q.